# What does "EXEMPT" mean on a car title?

Tags: used, odometer

So I'm looking to purchase a 2004 Acura TSX and the title showed that it had a EXEMPT on the odometer.

Car was listed at having 121k miles and upon further inspection, showed that it was sold at a dealer with 214k miles I assume around 2016 - 2018 when it was sold.

[image]

Does this have to do with the EXEMPT odometer title status? I'm in US, Texas if that makes a difference.

Comment: If the price is for a vehicle with 250k then up to you, if the price is for a vehicle with 121k then IMHO look at something else....

Comment: If it helps, according this (http://www.mytxcar.org/txcar_net/VehicleTestDetail.aspx?type=VIN&code=JH4CL96984C033216&rowId=169573566|WW599903&mode=N), it appears the 200k+ is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.txdmv.gov/motorists/buying-or-selling-a-vehicle/title-check-look-before-you-buy/odometer-brands) from the Texas Dept of Motor Vehicles, the Exempt reference means:

> The vehicle falls within criteria that allow it to change ownership
>   without disclosure of the odometer reading.